# SQL Structure help and query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can not find out what is wrong with my SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
                      productID int NOT NULL, 
                      name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
                      price int(255), 
                      PRIMARY KEY (productID) 
                      )

CREATE TABLE User ( 
                   userID int NOT NULL, 
                   PRIMARY KEY (userID) 
                   )

CREATE TABLE Purchased ( 
                   productID int NOT NULL, 
                   userID varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
                   date date(255), NOT NULL, 
                   FOREIGN KEY (productID) REFERENCES Product(productID) FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID) 
                   )
```

Please can someone help

Comment: Please tell us what error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax error in your `create table` statement.

- **Date** is a keyword so not a good practice to use it.
- **User_id** is **int** in your `USER` table and in `purchased` table you are making it **varchar**
- For **date datatype** no need to specify the **number of characters.**

The correct statement is

```
CREATE TABLE purchased 
  ( 
     productid INT NOT NULL, 
     userid    INT NOT NULL, 
     date1     DATE NOT NULL, 
     FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES product(productid), 
     FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES USER(userid) 
  )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dccb)

Comment: actually, a keyword can be used as a column name. it is not a good practice thought

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you have a syntax error in your third `CREATE TABLE` statement, where you have specified a comma before `NOT NULL` constraint and a missing comma before second foreign key definition.

Another thing to note is, you are not supposed to specify any parameter to `DATE` data type, like you have specified.

EDIT: The data type of userID in this table needs to be same as the data type of the user table for the foreign key to work.

The correct statement is

```
CREATE TABLE Purchased (productID int NOT NULL, 
                        userID INT NOT NULL, 
                        date date NOT NULL, 
                        FOREIGN KEY (productID) REFERENCES Product(productID), 
                        FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID) 
                        )
```

If you're getting some other error, please update your question

Comment: Wrong statement as this won't create the table. Foreign key datatype is different

Comment: @Gone Thanks! I have edited the answer. I failed to notice that

Answer (score 1):

In your query the problem is in date type column so no need to declare the date as variable because it is keyword in sql.

```
     1.Date is a keyword
     2.No need to size for date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date date NOT NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE Product (productID int NOT NULL, name varchar(255) NOT NULL, price int(255), PRIMARY KEY (productID));

CREATE TABLE User ( userID int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (userID) );

CREATE TABLE Purchased (productID int NOT NULL, userID int NOT NULL , date date NOT NULL,
                    FOREIGN KEY (productID) REFERENCES Product(productID),
                    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User(userID))
```

## [SQl fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6a18d)