# Return unique items in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT Product.name, Product.price 
FROM Purchased, Product 
WHERE Purchased.date1 > '2013-11-02' 
ORDER BY price DESC group by Product.name
```

Hello I am writing a query to return a list of unique products that were bought retailer’s site since November the 2nd with most expensive product returned first.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: maybe you should say in your query how the two tables are related

Answer (score 3):

You are using MySQL's group by extension incorrectly. Although MySQL allows you to put items in the select list that are not in the group by or an aggregate, it is not deterministic and ORDER BY will not help this.

The [MySQL documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) state:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

So even if your data was like:

```
ProductName | Price
------------+----------
     A      |  2.50
     A      |  3.50
     B      |  9.99
```

Using `GROUP BY Product.Name ORDER BY Price DESC` is not guaranteed to return the highest price for each product.  i.e.

```
ProductName | Price
------------+----------
     A      |  3.50
     B      |  9.99
```

What you are really saying is "give me one price per product (any price), then order the final results by price". So you could just as easily get 2.50 as the price for product A. I think you could get the results you want by using ``MAX`:

```
SELECT product.name, 
       Max(product.price) AS Price 
FROM   purchased, 
       product 
WHERE  purchased.date1 > '2013-11-02' 
GROUP  BY product.name 
ORDER  BY price DESC;
```

I suspect you are also missing a relation between product and purchased, this would be avoided if [you used the newer ANSI 92 explicit join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), the implicit join syntax you are using is 20 years out of date:

So your final query would be something like:

```
SELECT product.name, 
       Max(product.price) AS Price 
FROM   purchased 
       INNER JOIN product 
               ON product.id = purchased.productid 
WHERE  purchased.date1 > '2013-11-02' 
GROUP  BY product.name 
ORDER  BY price DESC;
```

*N.B. I have had to guess at the relationship between Product and Purchased*

Comment: very sharp answer ! +1 for the detailed clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    p.name AS Name, 
    MAX(p.price) AS Price 
FROM Purchased AS pr
INNER JOIN  Product  AS p
    ON pr.ProductId=p.ProductId
WHERE pr.date1 > '2013-11-02' 
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

I suppose that both your tables, Purchased and Product, have a productId column. This way each record to one table will relate with another record to the other table. If this is not the name of this column, please change the ProductId to the corresponding name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
SELECT Product.name, Product.price 
FROM Purchased, Product 
WHERE Purchased.date1 > '2013-11-02' 
ORDER BY price DESC GROUP BY Product.name,Prodcut.price
```

When you are using GROUP BY , you must include all the columns that you are retrieving in select class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need to do is find out how the tables are related to one another.  I'm going to assume that you have a productid column in your purchased table.

```
SELECT Product.name, Product.price 
FROM Purchased, Product 
where Purchased.productid = product.id
and Purchased.date1 > '2013-11-02' 
ORDER BY price DESC
```

What we are doing here is joining the two tables by the id column they have in common.  By doing this the database knows what data links together.

Lets say we have the

purchase table

```
PurchaseDate , Productid,  
2013-11-02       1
2013-11-03       2
```

Product table

```
id  ,  Product name
 1           Fuzzy Bunny
 2           Fuzzy bear
```

Now if you look at that data you know that on 2013-11-02 fuzzy bunny was purchased.  You can see this because the productid on your purchase table links back to the id on the product table.  That's how you figure out how to work with Joins in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your previous question.
[SQL Structure help and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775402/sql-structure-help-and-query/21775717#21775717)
Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eff083/1)

In the query,
`group by` should be before the `order by` clause.

```
SELECT product.name, 
       product.price 
FROM   purchased, 
       product 
WHERE  purchased.date1 > '2013-11-02' 
GROUP  BY product.name 
ORDER  BY price DESC;
```